# fatal error C1189: #error: <future> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt5

When porting Qt to 5.10.1, I am getting following error

**Reason for Error:** Visual studio Build with clr(Common language runtime ) support settings, so that above error is generated.

C/C++ Advanced > showIncludes sets "Yes", so It has been identified that from Qt's QThread above error is generated.

How to resolve above error in Qt 5.10.1 with VS2015 ?

*Note: I am using C# dll in my Qt VS project*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure QThread doesn't include when clr is enabled.

I have done conditional compilation for my project include

```
#ifndef CLR_ENABLED
#include <QtCore/QThread> //Error C1189: #error:  <future> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure. Qt5 porting.
#endif
```